# Como concatenar valores para futura insercion

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Hola que tal quisiera ver si pudieran resolver mi duda, tengo una linea para poder insertar valores en mi base de datos SQL Server, pero la verdad no entiendo porque no me sale la concatenación les dejo mi código, como envía el insert y como debería  de ser.

```
  $valores='('.$id.',"'.$ru.'","'.$ho.'","'.$ran.'","'.$ru2.'",'.$al.','.$an.',"'.$nom.'"),';
```

he imprime esto

> 12,"ru","ho","ran","ru2",0,0,"nom"

mientras deberia de imprimir asi

> 12,'ru','ho','ran','ru2',0,0,'nom'

Comment: Solo tienes que cambiar los `"` por `'` y viceversa.

Comment: @alanfcm lo coloque asi $valores='('.$id.','".$ru."','".$ho."','".$ran."','".$ru2."','.$al.','.$an.','".$nom."'),';     y me sale Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\AppServ\www\itic\insertar_registros.php on line 168

Comment: No cambiaste todas las comillas, solo algunas.

Comment: Tienes la boca llena de razon, gracias.

Comment: Este código parece estar abierto a inyección de SQL. Te aconsejo que aprendas a parametrizar tus consultas.